# Bootstrap. Выровнять содержимое по центру контейнера

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Имеется вот такой контейнер. Как выровнять его содержимое по центру? 
[image: А нужно, чтобы все это было по центру]

В bootstrap есть тег `center-top`. Я его пробовал по разному применять, но нужного результата он мне не дал. Код ниже.

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.top-cover {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  margin-right: 10px; 
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.top-name {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  max-height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container bgcont center-block">
  <div class="row background-row">
    <div class="centered-top">
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><div class="top-cover"></div><p class="text-center top-name">Oxxxymiron - Город под подошвой</p></div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><div class="top-cover"></div><p class="text-center top-name">Oxxxymiron - Город под подошвой</p></div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><div class="top-cover"></div><p class="text-center top-name">Oxxxymiron - Город под подошвой</p></div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><div class="top-cover"></div><p class="text-center top-name">Oxxxymiron - Город под подошвой</p></div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><div class="top-cover"></div><p class="text-center top-name">Oxxxymiron - Город под подошвой</p></div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><div class="top-cover"></div><p class="text-center top-name">Oxxxymiron - Город под подошвой</p></div>

      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><div class="top-cover"></div><p class="text-center top-name">Oxxxymiron - Город под подошвой</p></div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><div class="top-cover"></div><p class="text-center top-name">Oxxxymiron - Город под подошвой</p></div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><div class="top-cover"></div><p class="text-center top-name">Oxxxymiron - Город под подошвой</p></div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><div class="top-cover"></div><p class="text-center top-name">Oxxxymiron - Город под подошвой</p></div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><div class="top-cover"></div><p class="text-center top-name">Oxxxymiron - Город под подошвой</p></div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><div class="top-cover"></div><p class="text-center top-name">Oxxxymiron - Город под подошвой</p></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 text-center">` может поможет, а может и нет, без css стилей внутренних элементов трудно сказать

Comment: Не помогло. Добавил стили, посмотри, пожалуйста. Но не думаю, что там много чего интересного.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В бутстрапе есть класс `.center-block`, который [превращает элемент в блок и выравнивает его по центру контейнера](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-center). Нужно использовать именно его, а не `.center-top` или `.centered-top`.

Чтобы этот класс выровнял блоки по центру ячеек, нужно применить его к самим блокам, а из `.top-cover` удалить `margin-right: 10px;`.

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><div class="top-cover center-block"></div><p class="top-name center-block text-center">Oxxxymiron - Город под подошвой</p></div>
```

Но строки кода и без того чересчур длинные и однообразные. А по сути `.center-block` добавляет к блокам `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;`. Поэтому можно задать эти свойства стилям `.top-cover` и `.top-name`, которые вы уже используете, и обойтись без `.center-block`. А к `.top-name` добавить ещё и `text-align: center;`.

Кроме того, `col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6` - это то же самое, что и `col-lg-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6`. Заменил для красоты на `col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6`. Теперь при разной ширине экрана получается две, три, четыре или шесть колонок.

Проверьте результат:

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.top-cover {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.top-name {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  max-height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

.top-cover,
.top-name {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container bgcont">
  <div class="row background-row">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><div class="top-cover"></div><p class="top-name">Oxxxymiron - Город под подошвой</p></div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><div class="top-cover"></div><p class="top-name">Oxxxymiron - Город под подошвой</p></div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><div class="top-cover"></div><p class="top-name">Oxxxymiron - Город под подошвой</p></div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><div class="top-cover"></div><p class="top-name">Oxxxymiron - Город под подошвой</p></div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><div class="top-cover"></div><p class="top-name">Oxxxymiron - Город под подошвой</p></div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><div class="top-cover"></div><p class="top-name">Oxxxymiron - Город под подошвой</p></div>

    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><div class="top-cover"></div><p class="top-name">Oxxxymiron - Город под подошвой</p></div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><div class="top-cover"></div><p class="top-name">Oxxxymiron - Город под подошвой</p></div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><div class="top-cover"></div><p class="top-name">Oxxxymiron - Город под подошвой</p></div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><div class="top-cover"></div><p class="top-name">Oxxxymiron - Город под подошвой</p></div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><div class="top-cover"></div><p class="top-name">Oxxxymiron - Город под подошвой</p></div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><div class="top-cover"></div><p class="top-name">Oxxxymiron - Город под подошвой</p></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.top-cover {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.top-name {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  max-height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

.top-cover,
.top-name {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container bgcont">
  <div class="row background-row">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><div class="top-cover"></div><p class="top-name">Oxxxymiron - Город под подошвой</p></div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><div class="top-cover"></div><p class="top-name">Oxxxymiron - Город под подошвой</p></div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><div class="top-cover"></div><p class="top-name">Oxxxymiron - Город под подошвой</p></div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><div class="top-cover"></div><p class="top-name">Oxxxymiron - Город под подошвой</p></div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><div class="top-cover"></div><p class="top-name">Oxxxymiron - Город под подошвой</p></div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><div class="top-cover"></div><p class="top-name">Oxxxymiron - Город под подошвой</p></div>

    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><div class="top-cover"></div><p class="top-name">Oxxxymiron - Город под подошвой</p></div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><div class="top-cover"></div><p class="top-name">Oxxxymiron - Город под подошвой</p></div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><div class="top-cover"></div><p class="top-name">Oxxxymiron - Город под подошвой</p></div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><div class="top-cover"></div><p class="top-name">Oxxxymiron - Город под подошвой</p></div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><div class="top-cover"></div><p class="top-name">Oxxxymiron - Город под подошвой</p></div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><div class="top-cover"></div><p class="top-name">Oxxxymiron - Город под подошвой</p></div>
  </div>
</div>
```