# Как сделать, чтобы блоки встали по центру

Tags: bootstrap

Как с помощью классов Bootstrap сделать, чтобы блоки встали по центру, а не прилегали к правому краю экрана?

```css
.row div {
  background: coral;
  min-height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 74px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sx-1 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-3 col-sm-offset-1">col</div>
    <div class="col-sx-1 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-3 col-sm-offset-1">col</div>
    <div class="col-sx-1 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-3 col-sm-offset-1">col</div>
    <div class="col-sx-1 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-3 col-sm-offset-1">col</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Возможно что то подобное вы сможете отыскать [здесь.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/525496/bootstrap-%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Класса `.col-sx-1` в бутстрапе нет. Если поставить `.col-xs-12`, то на экранах шириной до 767 пикселей колонки займут всю ширину экрана.
2. После `.col-sm-2` можно не добавлять `.col-md-2`, потому что он не меняет ширину колонки.
3. На экранах от 768 до 1200 вы назначили столбцам ширину в 2 колонки и отступ слева размером в колонку. Но 2+1=3, а всего колонок двенадцать. Вот и получается, что последний столбец занимает одиннадцатую и двенадцатую колонки и поэтому оказывается впритык к правому краю экрана.
4. На экранах от 1200 столбцы становятся шириной в три колонки, но вместе с колонкой отступа получается 3+1=4 и опять двенадцать делится на 4 без остатка. Поэтому снова крайний столбец встаёт впритык к правому краю.

Попробуйте использовать `.container` вместо `.container-float`. Тогда на экранах шириной от 786 пикселей будут отступы по бокам от контейнера.

Или можно сделать столбцы на разное количество колонок.

Или можно задать столбцы без просветов между ними, а внутрь столбцов добавить блоки с отступами.